# Evaluating the limit of a function using squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have some function.

$$
\lim_{t\to3} \ \sin{\left(\frac{1}{t-3}\right)} \ e^t \ (t-3)^2
$$

I want to evaluate it using the Squeeze theorem but I do not know what it means to do this. I know that my limit is $0$ and I know that the squeeze theorem says if  $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ then the limit of $g(x)$ must be the same as that of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$. However I do not understand how to implement this.

I would like to know how this works and what is happening with steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:       $ -1 \le  \sin{\left(\frac{1}{t-3}\right)} \le +1$

Comment: Isn't $\sin\left(\frac{1}{t-3}\right)$ undefined when $t = 3$?

Comment: Yes, but for evaluating limit your function need to be defined on a deleted neighborhood of point .  so you remove $t=3$ from real line then your function is well-defined  @Computer

Comment: So what are you saying here? I am actually just looking at $\sin\left(\frac{1}{-3}\right)$?

Comment: What he's saying is that even without knowing the value of the sine function, you end up with a function $f(t)$ such that $-e^t(t-3)^2\leq f(t)\leq e^t(t-3)^2$, so your limit is squeezed between the limit of these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the factor $e^x$, since $e^x$ is independent of $t$. Therefore we only have to look at $\sin{\left(\frac{1}{t-3}\right)} \ (t-3)^2$. For $t \in (2,4) \setminus \{3\}$ we have

$0 \le |\sin{\left(\frac{1}{t-3}\right)} \ (t-3)^2| \le (t-3)^2$.

This gives $\sin{\left(\frac{1}{t-3}\right)} \ (t-3)^2 \to 0$  for $t \to 3$.

Comment: Where do you get the interval (2,4)? $e^x$ is actually $e^t$... sorry. What is $\{3}$?